# How to test WinForm DataBinding?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, data-binding

I'm trying to test DataBinding within a WinForm application.
The following test case fails.

```
[Test]
public void TestOneWayEntityBinding()
{
    //Arrange
    var entity = new MyEntity();
    entity.SomeProperty = "someValue";
    var userControl = new MyUserControl();
    const string pattern = @"xxx";

    //Act
    userControl.textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", entity, "SomeProperty");
    userControl.textBox.Text = pattern;

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(pattern, entity.SomeProperty);
}
```

Even explicitely calling b.WriteValue() onto the binding instance b, does not work.

Thanks,
Marcello.

Comment: Surprise! Adding the following code in the arrange section makes the test pass.

            Form f = new Form();
            f.Controls.Add(entiIntervenutiUserControl);
            f.Show(); ...It seems that databinding just acts on controls owned by a visible form.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that also b.WriteValue() has to be called, where b is the Binding instance returned by DataBindings.Add(...). Otherwise, as suggested below by lazyberezovsky you can bind with DataBindings.Add("Text", entity, "Altri", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

Comment: So, what part of your question is not answered by my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your are trying to test .Net framework. You shouldn't write tests for code, that you don't own. Good option here is acceptance test, that acts on UI (e.g. [White](http://white.codeplex.com/)) by setting textBox text.

Btw, why `textBox` is public in your user control? Implementation should be hidden. Its good to have property like 'Pattern' of type `string`. And you should not expose that databinding used inside your control. So, if you don't want to exercise UI, then good test for your control will be:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldUpdateEntityWhenPatternChanged()
{
    //Arrange
    var entity = new MyEntity() { SomeProperty = "someValue" };    
    var userControl = new MyUserControl() { Entity = entity };
    const string pattern = @"xxx";

    //Act    
    userControl.Pattern = pattern;

    //Assert
    Assert.That(entity.SomeProperty, Is.EqualTo(pattern));
}
```

Ideally would be to mock entity and just verify that SomeProperty was set, because currently test could fail in two reasons: text box is not bound to SomeProperty, or SomeProperty setter works incorrectly.

UPDATE
Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datasourceupdatemode.aspx) why binding is not working after setting Text programmatically. In order to update binding when property changes instead of when its validating, use:

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", entity, "SomeProperty", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

UPDATE
Seems like control should be visible for validation. If you don't want to change DataSourceUpdateMode, and you don't run your tests on service without UI, then simple ControlTester will help you:

```
public class ControlTester : IDisposable
{
    private Form _form = new Form();

    public ControlTester(Control control)
    {
        _form = new Form();
        _form.Controls.Add(control);
        _form.Show();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _form.Close();
    }
}
```

Use it when acting on control under test:

```
using(new ControlTester(userControl))
    userControl.Pattern = pattern;
```

**LAST UPDATE:**
DataBining is not working for control which has not been created. So here options:

- Create fake form (with ControlTester)
- Run real form
- Call CreateControl() after instantiating it

I think last option is the best one. To make DataBinding work in test, you can simply call CreateControl() method:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldUpdateEntityWhenPatternChanged()
{
    //Arrange
    const string pattern = @"xxx";
    var entity = new MyEntity() { SomeProperty = "someValue" };    
    var userControl = new MyUserControl();
    userControl.CreateControl();
    userControl.Entity = entity;

    //Act    
    userControl.Pattern = pattern;

    //Assert
    Assert.That(entity.SomeProperty, Is.EqualTo(pattern));
}
```

Comment: Ok, ok. Actually, tha arrange section is not done manually as shown in the question. It is performed by an "auto-wireup" engine which manages databinding based on aspect-oriented attributes on entities. The test case was intended to test the correct wirings.

Comment: @Marcello, I've added test sample for you. In your original test you was acting on textBox, not on userControl, which supposed to be tested.

Comment: textBox is not public, but internal. Unit test project accesses internals by InternalsVisibleTo clause in the tested project. I agree on mocking entity: very useful hint. Thanks!

Comment: @Marcello problem is how databinding works. It supposed to be invoked on user actions, so your entity object updated on control Validating. After assigning textBox.Text property call e.g. textBox.Focus() this will update entity.

Comment: Btw better way to enforce validation is to call Validate/ValidateChildren on user control

Comment: Nor Focus() neither ValidateChildren() worked. The only solution seems to place userControl in a Form f and call f.Show() before changing testBox. Thanks for your ControlTester.

Comment: By default the textBox should be private, and you shouldn't make it visible for other classes, including internal.